# VS2008 adding pl\bin to %PATH%

Tags: visual-studio-2008, path

How do I add:

```
pl\bin
```

to my VS2008 PATH?

I read in a forum post:   . . . ensure pl\bin is in %PATH%

But I can't seem to find such an option in my VS2008 Project Properties, etc...

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%PATH% refers to the Windows system path. Go to Control Panel / System / Advanced System Settings / Environment Variables, where you can see the various variables,one of them being PATH.

If you are using a C++ project, there is also a possibility to change the list of directories searched during a build in Tools / Options / Projects and solution / VC++ directories

Comment: Thank you.  

I went to VS2008 Tools / Options / Projects and solution / VC++ directories.  

There is a bunch of paths, each beginning with $.  

So should I add $(pl\bin) or should it be $(C:\Program Files\pl\bin)

Comment: $(xxx) is meant to be used if there is an environment variable named xxx; if you have a known path, simply add it (without any $()).
The $() notation is useful for VS itself, as it needs entries pointing to its install dir (which can be changed during installation), .NET framework dir, c:\program files (which changes depending on the OS language), etc.